# Add class to active top level (grandparent) menu item

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm building a site with a mega menu. Here's what the structure looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active-grandparent">Grandparent
    <ul>
      <li>Parent</li>
      <li>Parent</li>
      <li>Parent</li>
      <li>Parent
        <ul>
          <li>Child</li>
          <li>Child</li>
          <li>Child</li>
          <li>Child</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Grandparent</li>
  <li>Grandparent</li>
  <li>Grandparent</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to add the class "active-grandparent" to the top level Grandparent `<li>` if you are on that page or a parent / child page.

WordPress gives each active `<li>` item a class of `current-menu-item`, but I need to specifically target the grandparent `<li>` only so I can add some styles for when it's active.

How is this achieved?

**Updated**
As pointed out in the the comments, I could use `current-menu-ancestor`. However, this is only being generated on the Grandparent `<li>` when you're on a parent or child page.

To clarify, if you're on the top level Grandparent page (/grandparent), these are the classes which are being generated within the `<li>`:

```
.menu-item
.menu-item-type-post_type
.menu-item-object-page 
.current-menu-item 
.page_item page-item-12 
.current_page_item 
.menu-item-has-children 
.menu-item-203
```

If you're on a parent (/grandparent/parent) or child page (/grandparent/parent/child), these are the classes which are being generated within the Grandparent `<li>`:

```
.menu-item 
.menu-item-type-post_type 
.menu-item-object-page 
.current-page-ancestor 
.current-menu-ancestor 
.current-menu-parent 
.current-page-parent 
.current_page_parent 
.current_page_ancestor 
.menu-item-has-children 
.menu-item-203
```

If it helps, here are how my menus are generated within the template file:

```
<nav class="sidebar-navigation">
  <ul>
    <?php
      $menu = array( 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' );
      // Left
      wp_nav_menu( array_merge(
        array( 'theme_location'  => 'left' ),
        $menu
      ) );
      // Right
      wp_nav_menu( array_merge(
        array( 'theme_location'  => 'right' ),
        $menu
      ) );
    ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It should get the class `current-menu-ancestor` or similar already.

Comment: `current-menu-ancestor` is only being generated on the Grandparent `<li>` when you're on a parent or child page. I've updated my question.

Comment: will you not achieve the same in this way:  `.active-grandparent` = `ul.menu-class > .current_page_item, ul.menu-class > .current-menu-ancestor` ?

Comment: I need to apply specific styles to Grandparent '<li>', not the parents or children.

Comment: Yes, `>` char ensure that this styles will be be applied **only** to first `.current-menu-ancestor` or first `.current_page_item` under `ul.menu-class`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Styling the top-level item if it's active or a child is active is possible with pure CSS. Use the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), `>`, from the top:

```
.sidebar-navigation > ul > .current-menu-item,
.sidebar-navigation > ul > .current-menu-ancestor {}
```

If you want to add a *new* class, you can use the [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) filter. One of its parameters is `$depth`, which you can use to affect only top-level items. To tell if it's child is active you can just check for the existence of the `current-menu-item` or `current-menu-ancestor` classes:

```
function wpse_310629_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( $depth === 0 ) {
        if ( 
            in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) || 
            in_array( 'current-menu-ancestor', $classes ) 
        ) {
            $classes[] = 'active-grandparent';
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse_310629_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thank you for both solutions, especially the functions alternative.