# Add active class to top-level menu items when viewing single for that post type

Tags: menus, filters

For a menu which has only top-level links to custom post type archive pages, how can I add the `.active` class to the top-level item when viewing that post type's single?

There's lots of similar questions on WPSE (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789438/how-to-add-active-class-to-wp-nav-menu-current-menu-item-simple-way) or [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310629/add-class-to-active-top-level-grandparent-menu-item)), but none seem to address my specific question and make use of `.current-menu-item` or `.current-menu-ancestor` (and associated) classes, which don't appear on my menu (as I assume because the single posts aren't part of the menu list structure).

The only way I can think to do this is check the current post type against the slug, but it feels a bit hacky (and doesn't allow for url rewrites, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using an adapted version of one of the answers from @mrbenhenson's link.

```
function custom_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){            
global $post;
if ($menu_item->type == "post_type_archive" ) {
    $classes[] = ($menu_item->url == get_post_type_archive_link($post->post_type)) ? 'current-menu-item active' : '';
}
return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'custom_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link, which will help you add the class for custom post types: https://gist.github.com/gerbenvandijk/5253921